# How can I set the start time in React Big Calendar?

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I'm using this setup for react big calendar:

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <BigCalendar
       selectable
       step={3}
       timeslots={10}
       events={eventsE}
       defaultView='week'
       onSelectEvent={event => this.onSelectEventDate(event)}
       onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => this.onSelectSlotDate(slotInfo) }
    />
  </div>
);
```

I'm using this plugin http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html

But the start time is always at 12AM
How can i change to start only at 8AM...and do not waste time slots.

Thanks in advance
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 16):

You have to set today date in state and after use.

```js
// For react-big-calendar: "^0.27.0",

// declare 'today' inside your component
const today = new Date();

// start time 8:00am
    min={
      new Date(
        today.getFullYear(), 
        today.getMonth(), 
        today.getDate(), 
        8
      )
    }
// end time 5:00pm
   max={
     new Date(
       today.getFullYear(), 
       today.getMonth(), 
       today.getDate(), 
       17
     )
   }
```

Comment: It works for start time but, how can you set end time, because after this change hours between 12pm to 8am would be disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'date' prop to your request date:

```
    render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <BigCalendar
       selectable
       step={3}
       date={new Date(Date.now())}
       timeslots={10}
       events={eventsE}
       defaultView='week'
       onSelectEvent={event => this.onSelectEventDate(event)}
       onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => this.onSelectSlotDate(slotInfo) }
    />
  </div>
);
```

anther prop you can use is 'defaultDate'.